# I need help making a PHP form parse code lighter

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a PHP form which allows users to enter up 99 items if they do so desire. I was hoping that PHP doesn't need me to parse each individule item and it can handle doing a loop or something for when there are many items enter.

currently my php looks like this

```
$item1 = $_POST['Item1'] ;
$item2 = $_POST['Item2'] ;
$item3 = $_POST['Item3'] ;
$item4 = $_POST['Item4'] ;
$item5 = $_POST['Item5'] ;
// etc, etc
```

But I don't want 99 lines of code if only 5% of people enter more than one item in the form.

Answer (score 4):

Have all the inputs  named `items[]` (note the `[]`). You can then access them all in an array called `$_POST['items']`. You can then iterate through all the values:

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $item)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Take care: If you swtich over to X(HT)ML use and the ID attribute, this [would create invalid markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).

Comment: @hakre: Only the `name` attribute has to be set, but thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

change the input-names like this:

```
<input type="text" name="items[]"/>
<input type="text" name="items[]"/>
<input type="text" name="items[]"/>
```

and you'll get an array:

```
$items = $_POST['items'] ;
foreach($items as $item){
  // walk throug items and do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your input elements like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Item[]" value="A" />
<input type="text" name="Item[]" value="B" />
<input type="text" name="Item[]" value="C" />
```

And then in PHP you will see this in `$_POST` as an

```
array(
    0 => 'A',
    1 => 'B',
    2 => 'C'
)
```

This is a standard PHP trick, and you can use it to get any elements automatically inside the same array when reading them from `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative :

```
foreach($_POST as $index => $value) {
  $item[$index] = $value;
}
```

Comment: All this does is essentially copy the `$_POST` array to `$item`.  That isn't useful here.  You might as well do `$item=$_POST`.

Comment: The original code just copies individual $_POST items as well, and does nothing with them. The original poster asked for a loop solution to this, nothing else. It's trivial to add filtering or what have you inside the loop.

Comment: fair enough.  Can you edit your post (even just changing 1 character) so I can remove my downvote?  It's locked in at this point until an edit has been made.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1;$i<100;$i++)
{
    ${"item".$i} = $_POST['Item'.$i];
}

//or you can use variables directly
//echo ($_POST['Item1']);
```

or you can change Item1, Item2, .... in form to `Items[]` and then call it like

```
$items = $_POST['Items'];
print_r($items);
/*
array
(
    [0] => "some" 
    [1] => "text"
    [2] => "another"
    [3] => "text"          
)
*/
```

Comment: this solution is almost as bad as the initial one. this is the perfect situalion for simply using an array.

Comment: reason: completely avoidable and messy looping to produce an array that can easily be received like it should be by doing a minimal change in the markup of the form. and: you're using a for-loop so this would give an array cotaining 100 fields even if just 2 items "should" be set... and if one tries to post more than 100 items, your code doesn't process them all.

Comment: this limitation may change in the future - and we all have learned that code should be easily maintainable. maybe theres another programmer adding something to the code in a few months and sees this "100" - how should anyone know that this is the maximum of inputs? who remembers to change this if the limit should be set to 150 in the future?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 4)=="Item") {
        $item[substr($key, 4)]=$value;
    }
}
```

Comment: getting an items-array is a lot simpler: just change the name of the form-elements.

Comment: @oezi, that depends on if order matters to you or not.  Besides, this really isn't complicated.